# Can I enable WiFi on a Ubuntu Live CD?

Tags: ubuntu

Is it possible to have working WiFi on a Ubuntu Live CD?

I can't click on network (networking is disabled).

If I type in `iwconfig`, the result is:

```
 Lo no wireless extensions.
erh0 no wireless extensions

Wlan0  IEEE 802.11abg ESSID:OFF/ANY
Modę:managed access point: not-associated tx-power=0 dBm
Retry long limit:7 thr:off fragment thr:off
Power management:on
```

Comment: Can you list the chipset used and model of the wifi adapter for your laptop? You can do this with `lspci | grep -ai -e wireless` and `lsusb`.

Answer (score 11):

It's simple in Ubuntu 12 using a LiveCD/USB.

1. Go to System settings → Software sources → Additional drivers
2. Select any available option other than "Do not use the device"
3. Hit "Apply changes"

Enjoy your WiFi.

Comment: When I click on "Apply Changes", the option toggles back to "Do not use the device" automatically. Do you know a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. Check that your hardware switch is not put to off. If toggling it does not help, turn *Wireless Networking* to on in the Network Manager.

To check whether wireless networking is blocked, run `rfkill list` in [a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and be sure that it looks like:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

(note the "no")

Comment: the result is: HP WiFi wireless LAN
Soft blocked:no Hard blocked:no

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, I've done it a lot of times. If you run the liveCD and then wait about 2 minutes the Additional Hardware application will let you know you have drivers to install. Alternatively you can manually go to the Additional Hardware app by searching for it.

Comment: But In Additional Hardware list is empty

Comment: Would you be able to list what wifi adapter it is?

Comment: I dont know its hp pavillion laptop.

Comment: @user36307 do you know that there are LOTS of models in the HP Pavillion series? Please be more specific.

Comment: The drivers should be okay, since `iwconfig` already lists wireless configuration.